# Why Remote Ip is not showing in Order in magento-2.1 admin panel?

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, abandoned-cart, ip-address

I have some orders in **Magento-2.1** admin panel. When I click on one order, then Placed it from IP it returns IP is missing. When I will work on localhost, then IP is showing. But when I will work on staging or production URL, then it is not showing. And Abandoned Carts is also not showing IP address. What is the problem behind that when i placed order through angular made frontend?

Comment: check your configuration, `Stores > Settings > Configuration > Sales > Sales` `Hide Customer IP `

Comment: It is Hide Customer Ip >No @KeyurShah

Comment: anybody help me......